# android cannot get sound to play from a notification

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I have the following code to produce a notification.  The notification comes up but no sound. I have the following code to pouyt the sound on

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

code listing

```
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)     gContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Teeth Alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(gContext, 0, new Intent(gContext, NotifyMessage.class), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(gContext, "Your teeth appoitmernt:", "Date:", contentIntent);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    manager.notify(1,notification);
    cDates.SetAlarm(i);
```

Ted

Answer (score 11):

You should try setting

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

or setting explicitly:

```
notification.sound = 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment, it did not work.  I found some code that usses the notification to vibrate and it sets a line in the manefest file for securty.  Maybe I should do the same, but I could not find any informtion about how to do it, any idears? Ted

Comment: There is no permission for using sounds, only for the vibrate. Are you sure, that no other notifications use the `1` as their `id`? It's a better practice to use the displayed text/tickertext's id here.

Comment: Both `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND` and `Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` worked for me.  Further more, I did not need vibration permissions to use `DEFAULT_VIBRATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you resolved this but I had the same problem and it's because you have

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

but you need to assign it first like

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

or more simply as @rekaszeru put

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```