# Phonegap Android StatusBarNotification plugin doesn't make a notification sound

Tags: android, cordova, android-notifications

I'm using Phonegap 3.0 and the [Phonegap Android StatusBarNotification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)

It works as expected (I can create notifications successfully) but it won't play the sound alert when a new notification is created. My sound and volume are set correctly. other notifications (like the one for new email) are playing a sound. I also tested this on multiple devices.

I was trying to change the flags in the java code to explicitly set the `Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND` flag. That didn't make any difference.
Also tried the `Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE` and `Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868490/android-cannot-get-sound-to-play-from-a-notification)

The key is to use

```
notification.sound = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```